# Javascript string extraction/reg exp help

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string in this format:

```
<!--Start 498-->
some stuff here
<!--End 498-->

<!--Start 498-->    
some more stuff here
<!--End 499-->
```

and so on.

How can I split this string to remove the content between a certain block of `<!--Start xx->` and `<!--End xx-->`?

For example, if I wanted to remove the text between `<!--Start 500-->` and `<!-- End 500-->`, how would I remove it?

Edit: What regexp can I use to replace these? I'm hopeless with Regexps :(

Comment: Dude, I love your avatar. Where did you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use String.replace with a regular expression to match the blocks and replace with an empty string

Something like

```
<!--Start \d+-->.*?<!--End \d+-->
```

would do the trick

Comment: It's never too late to learn!: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webreference.com/js/column5/rules.html would help.